# Image transition not working with Animate.css & Wow.js

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So before I used Animate.css & Wow.js , the image transtion was working...
here is my code :
---html---

```
<a href='#' target="_blank" class="tooltip">
     <img src='img/image.PNG' data-wow-offset="2300" class="wow zoomIn"/>
     <span class="tooltiptext">e</span>
</a>
```

---css---

```
img {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 8px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

When I deleted the animate.css line from the head, the transtion worked

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Because it override by those plugin, try this `transition: opacity.3s!important;`

Comment: @Pedram not working :(